# Skip the first column when reading a csv file Python

Tags: python, csv, skip

I'm trying to read a csv file and extract required data from it. My code looks like below.

```
import csv
file = "sample.csv"
def get_values_flexibly(file, keyword):
    def process(func):
        return set([func(cell)] + [func(row[index]) for row in reader])

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        first_row = reader.next()
        if keyword in first_row:
            return str(list(set([row[first_row.index(keyword)] for row in reader])))
        for index, cell in enumerate(reader.next()):
            if cell.endswith(' ' + keyword):
                return str(list(set(process(lambda cell: cell[:-len(keyword) - 1]))))
            elif cell.split(':')[0].strip() == keyword:
                return str(list(set(process(lambda cell: cell.split(':')[1].strip()))))
print get_values_flexibly(file, 'data')
```

where sample.csv looks something like below

sample.csv

```
h1,h2,h3
a data,data: abc,tr
b data,vf data, gh
k data,grt data, ph
```

I'd like to exclude first column from the output. My current output is `['a','k','b']` but I'd like it to be `['abc', 'vf', 'grt']` instead. How can I achieve this using csv reader?

EDIT- I have multiple files. Each file could have different headers and number of columns varies too. I'd like to have a script that works for all the files. Also, the header of the first column is always the same, "sample_column" for instance. I'd like to skip data from column with header "sample_column".

Comment: Is your keyword always going to be `data`?

Comment: @BorrajaX No. It varies.

Comment: can you (or would you mind) using a regular expression to remove the `keyword` chunk of your cell?

Comment: @BorrajaX I don't mind using it. However, I'm really bad at regex. I'd really appreciate if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so removing the `data` (or whichever the keyword is) could be done with a regular expression (which is not really the scope of the question but meh...)

About the regular expression:

Let's imagine your keyword is `data`, right? You can use this: `(?:data)*\W*(?P<juicy_data>\w+)\W*(?:data)*` If your keyword was something else, you can just change the two `data` strings in that regular expression to whatever other value the `keyword` contains...

You can test regular expressions online in [www.pythonregex.com](http://www.pythonregex.com/) or [www.debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/)

The regular expression is basically saying: Look for zero or more `data` strings but (if you find any) don't do anything with them. Don't add them to the list of matched groups, don't show them... nothing, just match them but discard it. After that, look for zero or more non-word characters (anything that is not a letter or a number... just in case there's a `data`: or a space after , or a `data-->` ... that `\W` removes all the non-alphanumerical characters that came after `data` ) Then you get to your `juicy_data` That is one or more characters that can be found in "regular" words (any alphanumeric character). Then, just in case there's a `data` behind it, do the same that it was done with the first `data` group. Just match it and remove it.

Now, to remove the first column: You can use the fact that a [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is itself an iterator. When you iterate over it (as the code below does), it gives you a list containing all the columns found in one row. The fact that it gives you a `list` of all the rows is very useful for your case: You just have to collect the first item of said `row`, since that's the column you care about (you don't need `row[0]`, nor `row[1:]`)

So here it goes:

```
import csv
import re

def get_values_flexibly(csv_path, keyword):
    def process(func):
        return set([func(cell)] + [func(row[index]) for row in reader])
    # Start fo real!
    kwd_remover = re.compile(
        r'(?:{kw})*\W*(?P<juicy_data>\w+)\W*(?:{kw})*'.format(kw=keyword)
    )
    result = []
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        first_row = [kwd_remover.findall(cell)[0] for cell in reader.next()]
        print "Cleaned first_row: %s" % first_row
        for index, row in enumerate(reader):
            print "Before cleaning: %s" % row
            cleaned_row = [kwd_remover.findall(cell)[0] for cell in row]
            result.append(cleaned_row[1])
            print "After cleaning: %s" % cleaned_row
    return result

print "Result: %s" %  get_values_flexibly("sample.csv", 'data')
```

Outputs:

```
Cleaned first_row: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
Before cleaning: ['a data', 'data: abc', 'tr']
After cleaning: ['a', 'abc', 'tr']
Before cleaning: ['b data', 'vf data', ' gh']
After cleaning: ['b', 'vf', 'gh']
Before cleaning: ['k data', 'grt data', ' ph']
After cleaning: ['k', 'grt', 'ph']
Result: ['abc', 'vf', 'grt']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both for the code and the explanation.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for considering this the *selected answer*. Let me know if you have questions about the code. I can edit the answer to add some clarifications. That could help someone else that finds this answer in the future (if you have questions, chances are someone else is gonna have them as well)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the dict reader:

```
data = {'h1':[], 'h2':[], 'h3':[]}

h = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
csvfile = open(dir)
reader = DictReader(csvfile)
for line in reader:
    data['h1'].append(line[h[0]][2:])
    data['h2'].append(line[h[1]][2:])  # Use indexing to get the bits you want
    data['h3'].append(line[h[2]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My bad. I haven't asked the question properly. I have multiple files and each file could have different headers and number of columns varies too. I'd like to have a script that works for all the files.

Comment: You can use the first row to make the data dict then add data into it, which might make the problem simpler...